# Configure a custom data type mapping for use with a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, type-conversion

I have a struct called `CaseInsensitiveString` which is just a wrapper that allows my program to work with strings without caring about their case.  When it is persisted to a DB, it is no different from a regular string, though, so I want to be able to use it with a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter` like this:

```
var myString = new CaseInsensitiveString("foo");
var param = new SqlParameter("@MyValue", myString);
```

Of course I can't do that because `SqlParameter` doesn't know about my `CaseInsensitiveString`.  I get a `System.ArgumentException` when I try to use it with a SqlDataAdapter:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   ConsoleApplication1.CaseInsensitiveString to a known managed provider
>   native type.

Is there a way to make my own mapping so that I can convert `CaseInsensitiveString` to a `System.String`?  I could imagine there being an interface that I'd have to implement on `CaseInsensitiveString`.  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not provide any information on this.

I guess, to put it more succinctly, my question is really: how can I coerce a data type into one that is supported by `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter`.

Comment: Even if you can map it, I assume you'd want it to actually do a case insensitive comparison on the DB, but that's based on the collation.  Only way to force it to be case insensitive always is to change the query to specify a Collation by adding something like `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I understand that the DB will treat it as it normally would with regard to collation, in other words I don't actually care about case when it's persisted.  That's why I specifically said that it's no different than a regular string when persisted.

Comment: In that case what's wrong with just doing `new SqlParameter("@MyValue", myString.ToString());`.

Comment: @juharr -- I know there are work-arounds.  That's not what my question is about.  Mostly it's a curiosity thing: can it be done.  But also, I have recently refactored and have many instances of `CaseInsensitiveString` which used to be just `String`.  I don't want to have to change each one by hand, ideally.

Comment: Have you tried creating an implicit cast to `string`?  Not sure if that would work, but maybe.

Comment: @juharr -- Thanks for the suggestion.  I've been toying around with that idea, but I'm worried it might introduce problems elsewhere as implicit casting is often a code smell.  In other words, it might accidentally leak behavior into my application above the persistence layer where I don't want the values to be implicitly-cast but want them to behave as intended w/ regard to casing.

Comment: You might want to look into the `SqlUserDefinedTypeAttribute`.  That seems to be how `SQLParamter` determines what the mapping should be for types it doesn't have specific cases for.

Comment: I do not know if it helps you but there is a User-defined Type in the `SqlDbType.Udt` and you can check it.