# Map a structure to native datatype

Tags: vb.net

I have the following structure:

```
Public Structure NonNullableString


    Public Sub New(Optional value As String = "")

        Me.Value = If(value, "")
    End Sub

    Private m_Value As String
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return If(m_Value, "")
        End Get
        Private Set(value As String)
            m_Value = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As NonNullableString) As String
        Return value.Value
    End Operator
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As String) As NonNullableString
        Return New NonNullableString(value)
    End Operator



    Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Value
    End Function

End Structure
```

Which i am trying to execute in an `SQLCommand` by placing it in a parameter,

```
Dim value = NonNullableString("Test")
Dim parameter = New SqlParameter("String", value)   
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(command) With {.Connection = _sqlConnect, .CommandType = type, .Transaction = _transaction}
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

This gets me the following error:

> **System.ArgumentException:** 'No mapping exists from object type NonNullableString to a known managed provider native type.'

Now I know this is because `NonNullableString` is not a native type, and that I should be using `Dim parameter = New SqlParameter("String", value.Value)`.

My question is, is there a way to actually map my structure to a native type so that I do not have to use the `.Value` anymore?

Comment: I'm pretty sure: no

Comment: Since the parameter to SqlParameter is Object, it doesn't realize it could use your Widening operator.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409212/configure-a-custom-data-type-mapping-for-use-with-a-system-data-sqlclient-sqlpar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types are hard-coded so you can't change it.
Look at the method which is used and which throws that exception at the `switch`-`default`: [`GetMetaTypeFromValue`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlEnums.cs,212e14b9e36a25dc,references):

```
static private MetaType GetMetaTypeFromValue(Type dataType, object value, bool inferLen, bool streamAllowed) {
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(dataType)) {
        case TypeCode.Empty:     throw ADP.InvalidDataType(TypeCode.Empty);
        case TypeCode.Object:
            if (dataType == typeof(System.Byte[])) {
                // mdac 90455 must not default to image if inferLen is false ...
                //
                if (!inferLen || ((byte[]) value).Length <= TdsEnums.TYPE_SIZE_LIMIT) {
                    return MetaVarBinary;
                }
                else {
                    return MetaImage;
                }
            }
            else if (dataType == typeof(System.Guid)) {
                return MetaUniqueId;
            }
            else if (dataType == typeof(System.Object)) {
                return MetaVariant;
            } // check sql types now
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlBinary))
                return MetaVarBinary;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlBoolean))
                return MetaBit;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlByte))
                return MetaTinyInt;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlBytes))
                return MetaVarBinary;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlChars))
                return  MetaNVarChar; // MDAC 87587
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlDateTime))
                return MetaDateTime;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlDouble))
                return MetaFloat;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlGuid))
                return MetaUniqueId;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlInt16))
                return MetaSmallInt;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlInt32))
                return MetaInt;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlInt64))
                return MetaBigInt;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlMoney))
                return MetaMoney;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlDecimal))
                return MetaDecimal;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlSingle))
                return MetaReal;
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlXml))
                return MetaXml;                
            else if (dataType == typeof(SqlString)) {
                return ((inferLen && !((SqlString)value).IsNull) ? PromoteStringType(((SqlString)value).Value) : MetaNVarChar); // MDAC 87587
            }
            else if (dataType == typeof(IEnumerable<DbDataRecord>) || dataType == typeof(DataTable)) {
                return MetaTable;
            } else if (dataType == typeof(TimeSpan)) {
                return MetaTime;
            }
            else if (dataType == typeof(DateTimeOffset)) {
                return MetaDateTimeOffset;
            }
            else { 
                // UDT ?
                SqlUdtInfo attribs = SqlUdtInfo.TryGetFromType(dataType);
                if (attribs != null) {
                    return MetaUdt;
                }
                if (streamAllowed) {
                    // Derived from Stream ?
                    if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(dataType)) {
                        return MetaVarBinary;
                    }
                    // Derived from TextReader ?
                    if (typeof(TextReader).IsAssignableFrom(dataType)) {
                        return MetaNVarChar;
                    }
                    // Derived from XmlReader ? 
                    if (typeof(System.Xml.XmlReader).IsAssignableFrom(dataType)) {
                        return MetaXml;
                    }
                }
            }
            throw ADP.UnknownDataType(dataType);

        case TypeCode.DBNull:    throw ADP.InvalidDataType(TypeCode.DBNull);
        case TypeCode.Boolean:   return MetaBit;
        case TypeCode.Char:      throw ADP.InvalidDataType(TypeCode.Char);
        case TypeCode.SByte:     throw ADP.InvalidDataType(TypeCode.SByte);
        case TypeCode.Byte:      return MetaTinyInt;
        case TypeCode.Int16:     return MetaSmallInt;
        case TypeCode.UInt16:    throw ADP.InvalidDataType(TypeCode.UInt16);
        case TypeCode.Int32:     return MetaInt;
        case TypeCode.UInt32:    throw ADP.InvalidDataType(TypeCode.UInt32);
        case TypeCode.Int64:     return MetaBigInt;
        case TypeCode.UInt64:    throw ADP.InvalidDataType(TypeCode.UInt64);
        case TypeCode.Single:    return MetaReal;
        case TypeCode.Double:    return MetaFloat;
        case TypeCode.Decimal:   return MetaDecimal;
        case TypeCode.DateTime:  return MetaDateTime;
        case TypeCode.String:    return (inferLen ? PromoteStringType((string)value) : MetaNVarChar);
        default:                 throw ADP.UnknownDataTypeCode(dataType, Type.GetTypeCode(dataType));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it answers my question and can be verified to be the case.